# Detect a keystroke in matlab while viewing a figure?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, keyboard

I'm trying to sort through some image data in matlab and want to prompt the user for input about a series of images.  Each time I show an image I want to pause and wait for a keystroke and perform a different action depending on what was pressed.

Current Best Solution:

```
responses = zeros(length(images),1);
for i = 1:length(images)
    im = imread(images{i}.fname);
    h = figure(1);
    imshow(im);

    % instead of just pause, I want to get the keystroke (k) that was pressed
    waitforbuttonpress;
    k = get(h,'CurrentCharacter');

    switch lower(k)
        case 'a'
            responses(i) = 1;
        case 'b'
            responses(i) = 2;
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `KeyPressFcn` property of the figure environment which should be set to a handle of a callback function that receives an event structure containing the character pressed. See the [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/figure_props.html#KeyPressFcn) for details and example.

Also you can look at the `CurrentKey` property of the figure environment but it will not give you a way to know when the key is actually pressed.